# Why I am getting missing template from a subdirectory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following in my `views/patients/show.html.slim`

```
== render 'era/header'
```

Of course, `views/patients/era/_header.html.slim` exists, though it throws a missing template error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate at /patients/12345
Missing partial era/header with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :slim, :haml]}. 
Searched in: * "/home/pablo/code/rails/tarjira/app/views"
```

If I use `== render 'patients/era/header'` works, same with `== render 'era_header'` (assuming I have a `views/patients/_era_header.html.slim` file). The latter makes me think that rails search the actual directory (`views/patients`), so I don't understand why in the first case I have to prefix with `patients/`.

I'm using Rails 4.0.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render a partial as part of a view, you use the `render` method within the view:

```
== render 'era_header'
```

This will render a file named `_era_header.html.slim` at that point within the view being rendered.

```
== render 'era/header'
```

This code will pull in the partial from `app/views/era/_header.html.slim`. Notice how the Rails is forming the path i.e, by prefixing `app/views` before the given path in `render` method call i.e., `era/header`. This is how `render` method is implemented in Rails.

Read the Rails Guide explanation for **[Naming Partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)**

Comment: I understand that. And I can infer it from the docs. But why, using for example `_partial.html.slim`, inside the `views/patients` directory, works when calling `render 'partial'`?. It does look for `views/patients/_partial.html.slim`, instead of `views/_partial.html.slim`.

Comment: That's how Rails has coded the `render` method as per the docs. If you want to dig more then here is the source code of [render method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6251eb992fce30029479832f63d1281cd9fa7f3c/actionview/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb#L261).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now that you lead me to the source code I understand. This leads me to another related question. If I use `== render 'patients/era/header'`, it means that if I call a partial inside the latter, I also have to use the *full path*. This make me think that I'm doing something wrong and Rails it's not meant for using subdirectories and calling partials from there. Am I using a wrong approach?

Comment: It depends on the use-case. Most probably you used the nested directory structure to keep a cleaner hierarchy within your application BUT in that case Rails wants you to specify the path explicitly.

Comment: Yep. That's why. Though, still feels weird. Maybe I should try to use layouts and nested layouts more. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help. Hope my answer guided you  in the right direction. If so, then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The desire for partial rendering with relative paths seems to have a long history. There's [an issue from 2011](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1143) and [a pull request from 2015](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22473).

For now if you just need 1 extra level as described in your question you can place a callback in your `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :_append_view_path

  def _append_view_path
    append_view_path("app/views/#{controller_path}")
  end
end
```

This way your views will gain the ability to use `render('subfolder/partial')` instead of `render('controller/subfolder/partial')`.